# Real-time database triggers Firebase notification vs. FCM

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I see here is event triggers https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events for RTDB and I watch onCreate() method.

> onCreate()`, which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime
>   Database.

When I create new insert into RTDB in this method I can notify user about new insert into database.

But my question is now I can make here notification and all mobile device in same time get notification?

Why I need to use FCM. With FCM I can choose which mobile device get notification and many more features about notification?

Comment: @KENdi do you know anything about my questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Database client in your app is (normally) only active when the app is running and in the foreground. So it can only receive the new data, while the user is actively using your app.

The Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK includes a service that is also listening for messages when the app is not in the foreground. That means that with FCM you can also notify the users when they are not actively using your app.

It is quite common to use a combination of the Firebase Database and Cloud Messaging:

1. If one user changes the state, write that change to the database.
2. Then use FCM to notify the other users that "something" has changed.
3. Finally when the other users open the app again, the app gets the latest state from the database.